# wifi adaptor not found ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: networking, wireless

I have tried all possible solution from google but none of them seems to work.
This is the output of `sudo lshw -class network`

```
  *-network                 
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   logical name: enp1s0
   version: 07
   serial: 30:e1:71:8b:5a:81
   size: 10Mbit/s
   capacity: 100Mbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8106e-1_0.0.1 06/29/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
   resources: irq:16 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:b1200000-b1200fff memory:b1000000-b1003fff

*-network UNCLAIMED
   description: Network controller
   product: RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   version: 00
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: ioport:3000(size=256) memory:b1100000-b1103fff

*-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   physical id: 3
   logical name: enp0s20f0u3
   serial: 2e:ec:f6:48:14:63
   capabilities: ethernet physical
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.42.241 link=yes multicast=yes
```

---

```
$ dkms status
bcmwl, 6.30.223.271+bdcom, 4.15.0-34-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8723de, 5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414: added 
rtlwifi-new, 0.6, 4.15.0-34-generic, x86_64: installed
```

Comment: What is result for `sudo modprobe -v rtl8723be`

Comment: @Jeremy31 no changes, still shows no wifi adapter found.

Comment: What did it say in terminal when you ran the command?

Comment: @Jeremy31 it just execute , no output shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is because of the bug reported [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1788997/) (as mentioned by [heynnema](https://askubuntu.com/users/4272/heynnema) in the [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1077589/816190)). Some systems are facing problems with kernel 4.15.0-33 while some with 4.15.0-34.

Try booting with previous kernel. In the grub menu choose `Advance Option for Ubuntu` and from there you can boot with the previous kernel. If all works fine remove the latest kernel.

**PS:** One of my friend had the same problem. Yesterday, I removed the latest kernel and booted with the previous one and all worked fine. In his case bug was with 4.15.0-34.

Comment: Thank you. I booted with 4.15.0-33(previous kernel) and it works fine. And finally removed the latest kernel(4.15.0-34).

Comment: Actually, a *later* kernel version works, too. Please see: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2401794

Answer (score 0):

If you've installed a dkms driver for the rtl8723be, then, in terminal...

```
dkms status
```

should tell you it's condition.

If you're using the 4.15.0-33 kernel, then possibly...

This is a known bug with the 4.15.0-33 kernel and the rtl8723be wireless device.

See this bug report [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1788997/comments/21) or [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1788997/).

Booting with a different kernel may workaround the problem until they fix it.

**Update #1:**

**dkms status** shows the problem. The **rtl8723de** driver is not installed. Does this driver also run the **rtl8723be**, which is what you have. You may need to `sudo dkms remove...` it.

What are you using the **rtlwifi-new** driver for? Did you try to use this driver for the **rtl8723be**? You should be using [this driver](https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new). Use the `sudo dkms add/build/install...` commands to install it.

Same question... what are you using the **bcmwl** driver for? You may also need to `sudo dkms remove...` it.

In terminal, type...

```
sudo dkms install rtl8723de/5.1.1.8_21285
```

** you may have to tweak this command based on the exact version/location of the source code. Type **man dkms** for help.

Comment: this is output of dkms status: ` bcmwl, 6.30.223.271+bdcom, 4.15.0-34-generic, x86_64: installed
rtl8723de, 5.1.1.8_21285.20171026_COEX20170111-1414: added
rtlwifi-new, 0.6, 4.15.0-34-generic, x86_64: installed`

Comment: @MohitMalik  Although it's kind of hard to read when this kind of text is placed into comments, instead of edited into your question, please see the update to my answer.

Comment: @heynnema The bug doesn't only seem to be with 4.15.0-33 but also for 4.15.0-34 for some devices. One of my friend had the same problem with 4.15.0-34 but with 4.15.0-33, everything is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I spent four hours trying to resolve the "Wi-Fi adaptor not found" issue by checking the help comments from the internet. I tried many options but they did not help me to resolve the issue.

Finally, I came to know it was a simple set up issue in my Dell Ubuntu laptop. Somehow I pressed <kbd>F2</kbd> before which disabled my Wi-Fi setting and the Wi-Fi connection was not working.

It started working when I pressed <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> in Dell Ubuntu laptop to enable Wi-Fi.